# Class 'League\Glide\ServerFactory' is not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

im trying to use `League Glide` for showing my image, here is my code:

```
require(APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php');
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;

function league_image(){
    $array = array(
      'source' => new Filesystem(new Local(realpath(APPPATH.'../../images'))),
      'cache' => new Filesystem(new Local(realpath(APPPATH.'../../images/cache/'))),
   );

    $server =  League\Glide\ServerFactory::create(
       $array;
    );
    $server->setSourcePathPrefix('source');
    $server->setCachePathPrefix('cache');

    return $server;
}
```

i got glide folder, using zip than i move it into `vendor`

and i got this folowing error :

> Fatal error: `Class 'League\Glide\ServerFactory' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\deal\application\helpers\image_helper.php on line 106`
> `A PHP Error was encountered`
>
> Severity: `Error`
>
> Message: `Class 'League\Glide\ServerFactory' not found`
>
> Filename: `helpers/image_helper.php`
>
> Line Number: `106`
>
> Backtrace:

guys can you guide me how this error shown? in `phpstrom` the class was defined if `Ctrl+click` and i going to the part of `ServerFactory`

Comment: I'm getting this same error in Ubuntu